# Jest configuration with .jestrc

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I would like to know whether it is possible to use .jestrc to store configurations as JSON with Jest v26.1.0 and above. I have tried this but it says that the configurations have to be of `.js, .mjs, .cjs, .json` file types.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config=.jestrc"
}
...
```

Is there a reason why the Jest team would not support .jestrc configuration files?

Comment: I did. Previous versions did support that kind of format. I think people should still be allowed to be curious about things: why they work in a certain way. Plus the thread ends with https://github.com/cpojer saying that it will be included in v20.

Comment: Did they? AFAIK Jest always required .json or .js for config. You can call it .jestrc.json if you wish. The problem with rc convention is that it doesn't give an idea what format is expected inside, could be YAML or JSON or whatever and thus ignored by linters. It seems to be considered obsolete in JS ecosystem, most tools don't use it.